# How to fine-tuning the new custom extraction generative ai in document AI via api?

Tags: python, nlp, cloud-document-ai, google-generativeai

The python API documentation from:

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/train-processor?authuser=2#documentai_train_processor_version-python

When used with the new Custom Extractor Generative AI, train a model with "custom" type. There's something that I can change to make the fine-tuning model?

In other words, it's possible make the fine-tuning part of this link from python API?

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/cde-with-genai?authuser=2&_gl=1*y46br4*_ga*ODc2NTg2MDg3LjE2ODcxNzg3NzA.*_ga_WH2QY8WWF5*MTcxMDk2NDUyMy4zMDkuMS4xNzEwOTY4NjE2LjAuMC4w&_ga=2.199928295.-876586087.1687178770&_gac=1.204611876.1709034556.EAIaIQobChMIo7nr6LnLhAMVK0FIAB1CrwzcEAAYASAAEgJm9PD_BwE